# Como puedo hacer un split de >= en Java

Tags: java, split

Necesito a partir de un string dado, poder hacer split de acuerdo a una serie de símbolos de comparación.

Estoy utilizando esta sentencia:

```
String[] partes = condicion.toString().split("<|>|=|<=|>=|or|and|not");
```

El problema, es que con `<, > = or and y not` lo hace bien y no hay problemas, pero con `<= y >=` no los coge bien y me lo deja en blanco.

Alguna idea sobre como hacer split de manera que me coja los dos símbolos?

Gracias

Comment: No entiendo bien el problema. A mi tu código me funciona bien. Puedes darnos un ejemplo de `condicion` que no te funcione y cual sería el resultado esperado?

Comment: Buenas, gracias por tu tiempo, pero el del comentario de abajo ya me lo ha resuelto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes usar una expresión regular para la primera parte `<|>|=|<=|>=`

```
String[] partes = condicion.toString().split("[<>]=?|=|or|and|not");
```

La primera parte `[<>]=?` busca cualquier carácter `<`, `>`, y seguido de 0 o 1 ocurrencia (el **?** detrás del igual sirve para ésto) del carácter `=`, por tanto contemplas `<, > <=, y >=`

Como ejemplo:

```
String condicion= "0<1>=2or3<=4or5and6<7=hola";

String[] partes = condicion.toString().split("[<>]=?|=|or|and|not");
for (String parte : partes) {
    System.out.println(parte);
}
```

Comment: Me resuelve el problema. Muchas gracias!! No me estaba cogiendo bien en una prueba el >= pero con tu expresión regular funciona perfecto